# How to navigate the panel by keyboard to launch applications in XFce4?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, panel

In most applications, I can use <kbd>Tab</kbd>-<kbd>Tan</kbd>, to navigate from one button to the next, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select it.

I placed several launchers on the XFce4 panel.

Is there any way to launch items located there by navigating with the keyboard using <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or similar keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is possible. The key problem here is, that the panel does neither become an active window when you hover over it with mouse nor does it grab the keyboard. Which means it is probably not receiving the keyboard events at all.

See also related [discussion](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6682) where a workaround via `xdotool` is suggested. If you decided to go down that road, you probably want to save the mouse position and restore it after all is done.